# Passing local struct to count_if

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to pass an anonymous struct to std::count_if, which is failing to compile.

When I try to compile (with g++ 4.5.3, not using the c++03 or c++11 extensions), I get an error in the `fail()` method, but the `pass()` method does not have that error.

```
In function ‘void fail()’:
Test.cpp:34:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘count_if(std::map<int, int>::iterator, std::map<int, int>::iterator, fail()::<anonymous struct>&)’
```

I get a similar error if I make the struct a named struct.  I do not see why declaring it outside versus inside the function should make a difference.  What am I missing?

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<int, int> Map;

void fail()
{
  struct {
    bool operator()(Map::value_type const& value)
    {
      return value.second > 0;
    }
  } checker;

  Map map;
  std::count_if(map.begin(),
                map.end(),
                checker);
}

struct Checker {
  bool operator()(Map::value_type const& value)
  {
    return value.second > 0;
  }
};
void pass()
{
  Map map;
  Checker checker;
  std::count_if(map.begin(),
                map.end(),
                checker);
}
```

Comment: IIRC this is not allowed in C++03, but is in C++11. So you could try compiling with a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Of course in C++11, you could use a lambda as well.

Comment: "This" — using a local type as a template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++03 specification it isn't allowed to use local types as template parameters. This restriction was lifted with the 2011 revision of C++.

The basic reason for the restriction were concerns about creating unique names for the local types. There were, however, techniques developed to create unique names which work for all systems.

Answer (score 0):

In C++03,C++98, local/unnamed types could not be used as template arguments (STL algorithms)

Compile using `-std=c++11` flag

See [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#local-types)

And since C++11 is used, why not simply use lambda functions for `std::count_if`

Comment: I said that I am *not* using C++11 or C++03.  I hope that we can switch to using that, but the project has resistance to change.